# Reading manifest: Error processing options_page: An unexpected property was found in the WebExtension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

When trying to load the chrome extension in mozilla firefox. I have error:

> Reading manifest: Error processing options_page: An unexpected
>   property was found in the WebExtension Reading manifest: Error
>   processing options_page: An unexpected property was found in the
>   WebExtension manifest.

```
{
  "name": "EXTENSION",
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "icon-34.png"
  },
  "commands": {
    "_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+A"
      }
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "https://*/",
   "http://*/"
  ],
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: I think options_page may be depreciated, try options_ui https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/options_page

Comment: @TomBerghuis  When I add: "options_ui": "options.html", I have error: `Extension is invalid
Reading manifest: Error processing options_ui: Expected object instead of "options.html"`

Comment: "options_ui": {
  "page": "options.html"
}

Answer (score 8):

*"This manifest key has been deprecated. Use options_ui instead."*

```
 "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "open_in_tab": false
  },
```

---

references:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/options_ui

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options